# Magento 2.3.4+ When to Cache User Defined Attributes?

Tags: magento2

Since version 2.3.4 Magento has an option to **Cache User-Defined Attributes**.

Source: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html

What are the best practices to use this? It is disabled by default.

- In which scenarios do we want to enable this?

Or the other way around: when is it a bad idea to use this?

I presume when the store has too many custom attributes? How many is too much? 20? 200?